# Is the Riemann surface for the square root simply connected?

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, algebraic-topology, riemann-surfaces, covering-spaces

I am looking for universal covering spaces and I am now wondering if the Riemann surface for the square root $z^{1/2}$ (or even more general for $z^{1/n}$) is simply-connected and therefore a universal covering space for the punctured complex plane?

If so, is (the topology of) the Riemann surface for $log(z)$ homeomorphic to the Riemann surface for $z^{1/n}$? If both Riemann surfaces are simply-connected covering spaces for the punctured complex plane, then they clearly must be homeomorphic, but it doesn't seem obvious just from looking at them.

I am not familiar with complex analysis (I am specializing in geometry), but need an explanation for a result in geometry...so any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: The punctured plane is homeomorphic to $\mathbb S^1\times\mathbb R$, and hence its universal covering space is $\mathbb R\times\mathbb R$. Typically, this is represented by the exponential function $z=e^w$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Riemann surface for $z^\frac{1}{2}$ is a copy of $\mathbb{C}^*$, and the covering map you want is $z \mapsto z^2$.

For $z^\frac{1}{n}$, it's still $\mathbb{C}^*$, and the covering map is $z \mapsto z^n$.

For $\log(z)$, the Riemann surface is $\mathbb{C}$, with covering map $z \mapsto e^z$.

Answer (score 8):

I'm assuming you're talking about the Riemann surface $\{w^2=z, w\neq0\}$ and the like. Then it is *not* simply connected. To see this, first note that it is a two sheeted covering of $\mathbb C\backslash\{0\}$, because it is locally a homeomorphism and every point in $\mathbb C\backslash\{0\}$ has two preimages. Then its fundamental group is a subgroup of index 2 of $\pi_1(\mathbb C\backslash\{0\})=\mathbb Z$, which is not trivial. More directly, if you let $z$ wind 2 times around $0$, $w$ will make a full turn and thus you trace out a loop in $\{w^2=z, w\neq0\}$. But if you lift this loop to the universal covering of $\mathbb C\backslash\{0\}$ by the logarithm (see the next paragraph), you will see you have moved $4\pi i$, so it is not a loop in the universal covering. The same argument applies to $\{w^n=z, w\neq0\}$.

In contrast, the Riemann surface $\{e^w=z\}$ is simply connected because it is homeomorphic (in fact biholomorphic) to $\mathbb C$. It is a covering of $\mathbb C\backslash\{0\}$ via the exponential map, and so you can lift any loop in the latter via the logarithm to see if it is nullhomotopic.

*Conclusion*: the Riemann surface $\{e^w=z\}$, being simply connected, is *not homeomorphic* to $\{w^n=z, w\neq0\}$ for any $n>1$.

Comment: This is very helpful! But I have one more issue: 
You stated: "The Riemann surface {ew=z} is simply connected because it is homeomorphic to the complex plane.
1) How can there be a map beween the infinite-sheeted Riemann surface and the plane, which is a well-defined bijective function and a homeomorphism?  I mean, how can it be injective ("one-to-one") if a point from the plane is mapped on infinite many sheets on the Riemann surface?
2) The Riemann surface for the square root is not simply-connected. Is this Riemann surface homeomorphic to the (multiply connected) punctured complex plane?

Comment: @eigenvalue That's why I used the set $\{e^w=z\}=\{(w,z)\in\mathbb C^2:e^w=z\}$ to identify the Riemann surface. It is homeomorphic to the complex plane via the map $w\to (w,e^w)$. The infinite-sheeted covering is $(w,z)\to z$, or $(w,e^w)\to e^w$, and it's a covering of the _punctured_ complex plane, not the complex plane itself. In short they're two different maps, and what's on the other side of the map is not the same thing.